# JavaScript Won't Load

Tags: c#, javascript, browser, chat

I'm a noob - please be gentle for this stupid question.

I'm writing an extremely basic application that serves as a C# wrapper for a Browser-Based chat window: https://www.purechat.com/w/cvadob.  Whenever I launch this code:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.purechat.com/w/cvadob");
```

The page will spit out Script Errors and will not load anything (webBrowser1 stays white).  I stopped the errors with:

```
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

but I have not been able to get the JavaScript heavy page to load.

Does anyone have any experience with this?  I tried downloading several open-source browsers written in C# from around the internet, and none of them would load the page.

*EDIT*

Here's all of my code - this application is super simple:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PureChat
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.purechat.com/w/cvadob");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's quite common for webengines are not compatible with javascript heavy pages, maybe investigate the packages your using in c#

Comment: are you using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser or System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser? anyway check the useragent in the header to see what IE version you are using, and infer JS support from that

Comment: I'm using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser

Comment: W're going to need more information than this to answer your question.  What kind of errors are you getting?  Is this all of your code?

Comment: I'm getting "Script Error - An error has occurred in the script on this page" & Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'trim'

I only get those when I turn 
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = false;

Comment: Does the page work on IE on your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the WebBrowser control runs in IE 7 compatibility mode. You can modify this behavior using a registry key called Browser Emulation.

Microsoft has a detailed list of all the possible keys:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem appears to be here in one of the linked JS scripts (CompiledWidget):

```
return f.trim();
```

Where the variable f is a string.  IE has only supported string.trim() since version 9.  Your WebBrowser control I suspect may be based on an earlier flavour of IE ? On my VS2010 setup I get your same error.  Haven't tried VS2013.